# FTP - Verificar existência de arquivo em nodejs

Tags: node.js, ftp

Tenho uma pasta num servidor, acessível via FTP.
Gostaria de saber uma forma em NODEJS onde passando o nome do arquivo, ele me retornasse se o arquivo existe ou não.
Achei uma implementação em DELPHI - [código](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/ftp-verificar-se-existe-um-arquivo-em-uma-determinada-pasta/239628)

Comment: Existem vários módulos de FTP Client para o node.js. O que você pode fazer é implementar algum, tentar dar um Get no arquivo que deseja e o retorno vai indicar se ele existe ou não.

Comment: O problema que encontrei foram dois: se usar um list, a pasta é grande e pode quebrar o parser, trazendo inconsistência. Se eu implementar o código e pedir o arquivo, o sistema já inicia o download. Por isso a minha idéia era descobrir se existe algum paramentro, seja ftp ou curl onde eu passando o nome ele me retornasse um 200 ou 404...

Comment: Inclua em sua pergunta o código que você já desenvolveu e informe qual módulo do node está usando para o cliente FTP. 200 ou 404 são status do protocolo `HTTP`, não tenho certeza se os códigos do `FTP` são os mesmos.

Comment: acabei de achar um código em PHP http://codigosnaweb.com/forum/Verificar-se-um-arquivo-existe-em-um-servidor-remoto-curl-PHP_1_10027.html   . Observei que o desenv usou uma funcão pra retornar o código da resposta. acho que pode ser um caminho...